# Laravel 8. Как подключить внешний php файл в контроллер

Tags: php, laravel, include

Всем привет.
Переношу старый сайт на Laravel, заодно обучаясь ему.
В отдельном файле реализована некая логика (600 строк). Как подключить php файл Includ`ом ?
пробовал:

```
include storage_path('myfile.php');
```

Получаю ошибку что файл в директории domains/mysite/storage/myfile.php отсутствует

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Создайте например модель в которой реализуете эти методы и подключайте ее стандартными методами Laravel.

Comment: Это большой код и не относится к модели. Есть другой вариант ?

Comment: инклюдить файл в контроллер такое себе решение, как на счет сервиса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю создать директорию `app/Services`. Туда перенести Ваш файл `myfile.php` и переименовать его, например, на `SomeActionService.php`. В начале файла прописать пространство имён:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services;
```

Создать класс и туда перенести все функции, если это ещё не сделано.

Далее везде, где вам нужен функционал класса, вы подключаете файл:

```php
use App\Services\ClassName;
```

И используете методы :)

В дальнейшем сложную бизнес-логику можно реализовывать в отдельных Service-классах, а затем, используя внедрение зависимостей Laravel, внедрять классы в методы в контроллере.